# Codeigniter session discard some data after certain limit is reached

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-form-helper

I have 6 forms which are divided in steps for eg. 
Step 1

Next button : click here to go Step 2

Next button : click here to go Step 3

.
.
.

Next button : Last Step 6 "Finish button"

I save all form data in following manner from form 1 to form 6 (I dont want to use database for storing session data at all, i will write session data to db tables when user completes step 6 and click on button "Finish")

```
$form_data_step_1_to_6 = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($form_data_step_1_to_6);
```

Codeigniter session discards form data after form4, Session data in incomplete. Is there any way i can store large amout of data in codeigniter session without using database?

Comment: I don't think the issue is session size limits, but why don't you do one session per form then ?

Comment: what CI version are you using, and in `application\config\config.php`, how are your `$config['sess_*']` defined?

Comment: Thanks @AdrienXL  for ur response ...I am appending session form data when users click on go to next steps. My next form is dependent on selections of previous form, When user clicks on Finish.  I will process session array and save all the data to their receptive table...

Comment: Ci version is 2.2.1 . Config setting is default

Answer (score 1):

are you using ajax to store data in session/ if yes then its not session size limit issue. then its session expire time issue.

Comment: Not using ajax. Just CI session library

Comment: how you are saving data to session by posting data to server and refreshing page or by ajax.